# Filter out data with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, yii

I retrireve data from my MySQL database into a simple table. Above this table I should have a text-input. On entering a keyword into this input, I want to cancel all showing data in the table and display data, found by %LIKE% operator, matching the keyword entered.
Something similar does jQueryUi Autcomplete, FooTable and a couple of Yii extensions, but I wanna do it all from scratch. Any ideas on how to do it? Links?
My knowledge:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(){
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Search MySQL ajax search  on google or try this example  [http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am going to give you is not the complete code.
You want to do it yourself so here is only the logic.

In you index.php file

```
<input type="text" name="autocoplete" id="autocomplete"/>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('keyup', '#autocompelte', function(){

        var text = $('#autocomplete').val();

        $.post('process.php', {text:text}, function(resultData){
            //Treat your resultData and convert into HTML for example
            $('#result').html(myHTMLResult);
        }, 'json'); //I want my result as JSON
    });
</script>
```

process.php

```
if(true === isset($_GET['text']) && false === empty($_GET['text']))
{
    //Do your query where you field is like %$_GET['text']% : example : SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield like %$_GET['text']%
    //Store all your result in an array
    //Format this array into json to be easy to treat with json
    //Send this json back to your index.php file.

    echo json_encode($listResult);
}
```

Comment: You should clean your tbody before using append. And you are asking help but where is the problem now ?

Comment: The problem is I am inputing data to the input, but the table is not populated. My json looks like this: [["4",null,"SICO \u21163 \u041c\u0430\u0440\u0430\u0444\u043e\u043d \u041a\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0447. 3\u0448\u0442, \u0420\u0424","1","2","SICO"]]

Comment: Remove response when you loop on jsondata. So change `$.each(jsondata.response, function(i, d)()...` in `$.each(jsondata, function(i, d)()...`.

Answer (score 0):

@ThinkTank thank you very much for the help. It works just fine. Here is my final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#input').keyup(function(eventObject){
            //cancel all displaying data in the table if keyword exists
            if($(this).val()) {
                //$("td").hide();
                $("td").remove();
                //data hid, now send data to server
                var orgValue = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/products/RetrieveData',
                    data: 'term='+orgValue,
                    success: function(data) {
                        var jsondata=$.parseJSON(data);
                        $.each(jsondata, function(i, d) {
                            var row='<tr>';
                            $.each(d, function(j, e) {
                                row+='<td>'+e+'</td>';
                            });
                            row+='</tr>';
                            $('#table tbody').append(row);
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("td").show();
            }
        });
    } );
```

Just some ideas:
1. Once I find (filter out) what I need, I clear the input with backspace. How do I set the table to the initial state with the data?